# how to chat between 2 ubuntu machines in network?

Tags: ubuntu, messenger

I want to know that how we can chat between 2 ubuntu machines in a network.

any command line chat messenger for 2 ubuntu in network?
or GUI will also work.

I am asking about "network chat messengers".

Comment: why down marked question? all are not expected to be knowledgeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use freenode from empathy messenger & join the room.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Internet Relay Chat and communicate in this manner.  That's probably the easiest solution as you can just download an IRC client like http://www.bitchx.org or http://irssi.org.  There are many IRC servers you both could connect to, create your own channel, and chat away.